# Feature error when deploying a master page with visual studio 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, feature-activation, visual-studio-2013

I am new in working with VS13 to edit master pages, when I try to deploy it gives an error:

> Error  30  Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id '294c74bc-089c-49f1-91b3-97a75b696cbc' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.
>               0   0   Custom Masterpage

Any help on how to install the feature?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you deploy a feature to a multi server as it cannot activate the solution. The quickest way it to build the solution in vs 2013 and install manually with powershell - this is the same for SP2010 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvarro/archive/2011/11/06/sharepoint-2010-amp-visual-studio-2010-error-ocurred-activate-features-feature-with-id-installed-in-this-farm-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope.aspx